# Enable security create errors in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I am using Extended email notification plugin in Jenkins. For formatting the recipient email ids I am using a pre-send script in groovy which is successfully compiling when the jenkins security is disabled. But when I am enabling the security it shows an exception
[ScreenShotError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3EW7.png)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tomcat\Groovy (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome!
Please refer to this link to help others help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask